# Translucent Vim map for short manual about keys after it

Tags: vim

In (Neo)Vim, I want to configure a key as if it passed through one-way mirror.

For example, in normal mode, when I type `<Leader>`, the command `:echo "w: Separate Window f: Open File c: Configure Settings"` run (so I can get help from at the bottom of the screen), but the `<Leader>` *still* has influence on following keys --- such as `w`, `f`, `c`, and so on --- and `<Leader><KEY>` works properly.

I mapped lots keys with `<Leader>`, so it will be very helpful for me to display a short manual about keys follow `<Leader>` at the bottom of the screen when I type `<Leader>`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the following mapping:

```
:nnoremap <Leader> :echo "w: Separate Window f: Open File c: Configure Settings"<Bar>call feedkeys((exists('g:mapleader') ? g:mapleader : '\'), 't')<CR>
```

This uses `feedkeys()` to send the `<Leader>` again after the help has been shown. However, this solution has the key timeout downsides already mentioned by @romainl: The message will only appear after the `'timeoutlen'` delay, and then you have to press the correct mapping key within `'timeoutlen'`.

#### alternative

I would rather print the help on `<Leader><Leader>`. There are no timeout issues here. If you have pressed `<Leader>` and then fail to remember what's the next key, just press `<Leader>` again, read the help, and then start again with the (now memorized) full mapping!

Comment: Thanks, it works!
Indeed the `'timeoutlen'` causes me, but I satisfied with your command very much.

Comment: Ah, great! If this answers your question, please accept it by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

First, `<leader>` is not a special key at all. It's a placeholder expanded by Vim to the current value of `mapleader` whenever it is used. Assuming your `mapleader` is `,` (as instructed in `:help mapleader`), the mapping below:

```
nnoremap <leader>f :find *
```

will be registered as:

```
nnoremap ,f :find *
```

Second, when Vim detects that the key you just pressed is part of several custom or built-in commands it waits a bit for you to press more keys in order to decide what to do. With `,` as your `mapleader`, pressing `,` will *always* puzzle Vim because `,` is an actual command in its own right and you have a bunch of custom mappings starting with `,`. In this situation, Vim waits for a full second before deciding you actually wanted `,` and not `,f`.

Third, you would almost certainly need to write a completely separate mapping mechanism for achieving you idea. A mechanism that would:

- listen to key presses,
- trigger a specific function when you press `<leader>`,
- that prints something helpful in the command-line,
- and waits indefinitely for another key to be pressed.

This doesn't sound trivial at all. Did you take a look at the "scripts" section of http://www.vim.org?

Four, the whole point of a mapping is to *map* a common action to an easy to remember shortcut. You definitely have too many mappings if you can't remember all of them. Maybe it's time to reconsider the root issue instead of looking for a workaround?

Comment: I see.
I told what I want to do too informal, sorry. I will be careful about that.
And I will try useful Vim script in vim.org.
Thanks a lot.